# Multidimensional Associative Array in Excel VBA

Tags: php, vba, excel

I'm trying to create variable in Excel VBA that contain data like this in 'php'

```
$classroom['group1']['sub_group1']['John']['math']['pretest'] = 20;
$classroom['group1']['sub_group1']['John']['math']['posttest'] = 50;
$classroom['group1']['sub_group1']['John']['science']['pretest'] = 26;
$classroom['group1']['sub_group1']['John']['science']['posttest'] = 45;

$classroom['group1']['sub_group1']['David']['math']['pretest'] = 40;
$classroom['group1']['sub_group1']['David']['math']['posttest'] = 44;
$classroom['group1']['sub_group1']['David']['science']['pretest'] = 15;
$classroom['group1']['sub_group1']['David']['science']['posttest'] = 17;

$classroom['group1']['sub_group2']['Kate']['math']['pretest'] = 15;
$classroom['group1']['sub_group2']['Kate']['math']['posttest'] = 30;
$classroom['group1']['sub_group2']['Kate']['science']['pretest'] = 26;
$classroom['group1']['sub_group2']['Kate']['science']['posttest'] = 40;

$classroom['group1']['sub_group2']['Alice']['math']['pretest'] = 14;
$classroom['group1']['sub_group2']['Alice']['math']['posttest'] = 35;
$classroom['group1']['sub_group2']['Alice']['science']['pretest'] = 28;
$classroom['group1']['sub_group2']['Alice']['science']['posttest'] = 42;

echo json_encode($classroom);
```

the result I want it to be should be heirarchy structure as the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Eb4x.jpg)

I tried to use dictionary but my data have duplicated key.

What should I do in order to get the result I want it to be and what kind of variable type should I use?

Thank you.

Comment: The question is ... why did your dictionary have a duplicated key?  (And at which level did it have it?)  The first `Dictionary` should have had one key (`"group1"`).  The `Dictionary` that was the value for `"group1"` should have had two keys (`"sub_group1"` and `"sub_group2"`).  The `Dictionary` that was the value for `"sub_group1"` should have had two keys (`"John"` and "`David`").  Both the `Dictionary` for `"John"` and the one for `"David"` should have had two keys (`"math"` and `"science"`), etc.  None of those `Dictionary` objects would have had duplicate keys.

Comment: It might be best if you include your code into the question.  That way we can help you fix it so that it works.

Comment: If you wish to use these data in Excel you might be well advised to bear in mind that Excel is basically three-dimensional, sheets, columns and rows. A fourth dimension is possible by using different workbooks. However the task you describe can easily be solved on a single worksheet, meaning two dimensions, meaning a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: You could use simple `VBA.Collection` type. Create your own class for `group` which will hold collection of `sub-groups` which will hold collection of `people` which hold collection of `subjects` etc. :). The `Dictionary` is possible as well, but collection is sufficient here I guess. To be able to add items to dictionary though each item has to have unique ID. In case of a VBA.Collection you can use key as well, but you can use Collection like a `bag` for some items. but in that case you can't access them by key but you will have to enumerate them one after another.

Comment: If you have `json` data and need to parse them in `VBA`, then some `json` parsers for `VBA` exist already e.g. [this one](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON).